# Массив объектов класса

Tags: c++

Описать абстрактный класс Музыкальный инструмент. Класс должен содержать характеристики: название, фирма-производитель, стоимость, функцию вывода всех данных на экран. На его основе реализовать классы Духовой инструмент, Фортепиано, Струнный инструмент. Задать отдельные характеристики классов, например, год выпуска, количество струн и т.п

Создать массив объектов класса Оркестр, модифицировать его, поместив в его начало все Духовые инструменты.
Создал класс оркестр и сталкиваюсь с новой проблемой. Мне нужно выводить данные записанные с помощью Case 1, но как их использовать правильно в Case 3, при этом поставив все духовые на первое место просто не знаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Класс музыкальные инструменты
class instrument
{
protected:
    string name, firm;
    int cost;
public:     
    instrument(): name("NULL"), firm("NULL"), cost(0)
    {}

    virtual ~instrument() = default;

    void GetInst()
    {
        cout << "\nВведите название инструмента: "; cin >> name;
        cout << "Введите производителя: "; cin >> firm;
        cout << "Введите цену: "; cin >> cost;
    }
    void PutInst()
    {
        cout << "\nИнструмент: " << name;
        cout << "\nПроизводитель: " << firm;
        cout << "\nЦена: " << cost;     
    }
    virtual void GetData() = 0; 
    virtual void PutData() = 0;
};

//Духовые инструменты
class WindInst: public instrument
{
protected:
    int year, LC; //LC - длина канала
    string material, color; 
public:
    WindInst(): material("Metal"), color("White"), year(2018), LC(0)
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nДуховой" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Введите длину канала духового инструмента: "; cin >> LC;
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
        cout << "Введите цвет: "; cin >> color;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        cout << "\nДуховой" << endl;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nДлина духового канала: " << LC;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material;
        cout << "\nЦвет: " << color << endl;
    }               
};

//Фортепиано
class PianoInst: public instrument
{
protected:
    int year;
    const int NON, key;
    string material;
public:
    PianoInst(): key(85), NON(7), material("Tree"), year(2018)
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nКлавишный" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        cout << "\nКлавишный" << endl;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nКоличество нот: " << NON;
        cout << "\nКоличество клавиш: " << key;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material << endl;
    }               
};

//Струнные инструменты
class StringInst: public instrument
{
protected:
    int year, NOS; //Количество струн (NOS)
    string material, color;
public:
    StringInst(): material("Steel"), color("Red"), year(2018), NOS(0)
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nСтрунный" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Введите количество струн: "; cin >> NOS;
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
        cout << "Введите цвет: "; cin >> color;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        cout << "\nСтрунный" << endl;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nКоличество струн: " << NOS;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material;
        cout << "\nЦвет: " << color << endl;    
    }
};

class Orchestra: public instrument
{
private:
    WindInst mass1[100];
    int n1;
    PianoInst mass2[100];
    int n2;
    StringInst mass3[100];
    int n3;
public:
    Orchestra()
    {
        n1 = 0;
        n2 = 0;
        n3 = 0;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
            cout << endl;
            mass1[i].PutData();
            cout << endl;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++){
            cout << endl;
            mass2[i].PutData();
            cout << endl;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n3; i++){
            cout << endl;
            mass3[i].PutData();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    system ("chcp 1251 && cls");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = 0, s = -1, h=2;
    bool k = true;
    char choice;
    instrument* instK[h];
    WindInst w;
    PianoInst p;
    StringInst st; 
    Orchestra* mass[h];

    while(true){
    cout << "     Выберите дальнейшее действие: " << endl;
    cout << "1) Ввод инструментов" << endl;
    cout << "2) Вывод всех инструментов" << endl;
    cout << "3) Оркестр" << endl;
    cout << "0) Выход" << endl << endl;
    cout << "S=";
    cin >> s;
    system("cls");
    switch(s) {

    //Ввод инструментов
    case 1: {   
    do{
        cout << "Духовой (W), Струнный (S) или Клавишный(P): ";
        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 'W' || choice == 'w')
        {
            instK[n] = new WindInst;
            h++;
        }

        else if(choice == 'S' || choice == 's')
        {
            instK[n] = new StringInst;
            h++;
        }

        else
        {
            instK[n] = new PianoInst;
            h++;
        }

        instK[n++] -> GetData();
        cout << "Ещё инструмент (y/n)?";
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");
    }
    while(choice == 'y');
    system("cls");
    break;
    }

    //Вывод всех данных на экран
    case 2:{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        instK[j] -> PutData();
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    break;
    }

    //Оркестр
    case 3:{
    for(int p=0; p<n; p++)
    {
        mass[p] -> print();
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    break;
    }

    //Выход
    case 0:{
    return 0;
    break;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Наоборот, надо каждый инструмент наследовать от класса оркестр.

Comment: @Duoxx То есть духовой, клавишный и струнный будет наследоваться от класса оркестр и от класса инструмент?

Comment: Оркестр, это  набор инструментов.   Ваше задание не требует создать класс оркестр, а требует создать оркестр.  Возьмите любой контейнер  и заполняйте его адресами инструментов( instrument* ) , что  должно быть в оркестре .  Этот контейнер и будет оркестром. Я же вам это уже показывал

Comment: @ARHovsepyan преподаватель поменял условие) Сказал, что Оркестр - будет классом. А список - это массив. Она просто не подумав написала список, тем самым дезориентировала. Сказала, что список в данном случаи массив.

Comment: массив чего?..  Если массив оркестров, то зачем?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Насколько я понял его слова, нужно создать класс оркестр, в нём произвести модификацию, из-за которой духовые инструменты буду выводиться первыми. После чего создать массив типа оркестр и пройти по методу вывода на экран этой самой модификации. У меня проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно взять данные из записанных мной с помощью case 1 и использовать их для этой самой модификации, после чего вывести сначала духовые - потом остальные.

Comment: честно говоря я не  понел требования  вашего преподавателья, но класс оркестр  в таком случаи должен наследовать все музыкальные инструменты, что является   глупостью, или должен иметь представление в виде   множества инструментов

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Если например создать класс оркестр, который будет наследовать класс инструменты, его полями сделать массивы типа самих инструментов. Например массив духовые будет: WindInst mass1[] и т.д. После чего поработать с каждым массивом отдельно и выводить сначала все духовые, потом например все клавишные, а дальше струнные. Я понимаю, мне легко говорить, но такое вообще сделать возможно? И как в дальнейшем мне это вызвать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс-оркестр ничего не должен знать о конкретных инструментах, ему нужен только общий интерфейс инструментов. Для хранения списка инструментов можно использовать список указателей на инструменты, для сортировки - указать каждому инструменту приоритет, 0 - по умолчанию, 1 - для духовых, и сортировать по убыванию.

Вот основа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class Instrument{
public:
    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
    virtual int getPriority() const { return 0; }
    virtual ~Instrument(){}

    bool operator < (const Instrument& rha){ // Обратите внимание, это не виртуальный метод - он одинаков дял всех инструментов
        return getPriority() < rha.getPriority(); 
    }
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Instrument& rha){
    return out << rha.getName(); // Или можно сделать виртуальный метод "void print(std::ostream&) const", и вызывать его в невиртуальном operator <<
}

class Orchestra{
public:
    void add(std::unique_ptr<Instrument> newInstrument){
        if(!newInstrument)
             return; // Нулевой указатель игнорируем

        // Функция, разыменовывающая указатели и сравнивающая значения по убыванию приоритета
        auto priorityGreather = [](const std::unique_ptr<Instrument>& lha, const std::unique_ptr<Instrument>& rha){
            return *rha < *lha;
        };

        // Ищет итератор, перед которым можно вставить новый элемент, не нарушая сортировку по priorityGreather (сортировака по убыванию приоритета)
        auto insertIt = std::lower_bound(list.begin(), list.end(), newInstrument, priorityGreather);

        // Вставляет новый элемент на это место
        list.insert(insertIt, std::move(newInstrument));
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Orchestra& rha);
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Instrument>> list;
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Orchestra& rha){
    for(const auto& x: rha.list)
        out << *x << '\n';
    return out;
}

class WindInstruments: public Instrument{
    public:
    WindInstruments() = default;
    ~WindInstruments() override {}

    std::string getName() const override { return "WindInstruments"; }
    int getPriority() const { return Instrument::getPriority() + 1; }
};
class StringedInstruments: public Instrument{
    public:
    StringedInstruments() = default;
    ~StringedInstruments() override {}

    std::string getName() const override { return "StringedInstruments"; }
    // int getPriority() const { return Instrument::getPriority(); } // Оставляем по умолчанию
};


int main(){
   Orchestra orhestra;

   orhestra.add(std::make_unique<WindInstruments>());
   orhestra.add(std::make_unique<StringedInstruments>());
   orhestra.add(std::make_unique<StringedInstruments>());
   orhestra.add(std::make_unique<WindInstruments>());
   orhestra.add(std::make_unique<WindInstruments>());
   orhestra.add(std::make_unique<StringedInstruments>());
   orhestra.add(std::make_unique<WindInstruments>());

   std::cout << orhestra;

   return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
WindInstruments
WindInstruments
WindInstruments
WindInstruments
StringedInstruments
StringedInstruments
StringedInstruments
```

`std::unique_ptr` можно заменить на сырые указатели на `instrument`, если вам так понятнее.

Наследовать члены-данные не желательно, обычно лучше наследовать методы. Это удобнее для расширения.